# Exchanging rows in a transition matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the two bases $\mathcal{B} = \{\mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2, \mathbf{u}_3\}$ and the standard basis $\mathcal{E} = \{\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2, \mathbf{e}_3\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$, where
$$
\mathbf{u}_1 = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
3\\
2\\
6
\end{array}\right]
\quad
\mathbf{u}_2 = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
9\\
-1\\
4
\end{array}\right]
\quad
\mathbf{u}_3 = 
\left[\begin{array}{r}
-\frac{2}{3}\\
-2\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Then, the transition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ from $\mathcal{E}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ is given by
$$
\mathbf{A}_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{E}} =
\left[\begin{array}{r|r|r}
[\mathbf{e}_1]_{\mathcal{B}}&[\mathbf{e}_2]_{\mathcal{B}}&[\mathbf{e}_3]_{\mathcal{B}}
\end{array}\right]
\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} -{\frac{3}{49}}&{\frac{5}{49}}&{\frac{8}{
49}}\\  {\frac{6}{49}}&-{\frac{3}{49}}&-{\frac{2}{49}
}\\  -{\frac{6}{49}}&-{\frac{18}{49}}&{\frac{9}{49}}
\end {array} \right] 
$$
We thus have
$$
[\mathbf{u}_1 \text{ } \mathbf{u}_2 \text{ } \mathbf{u}_3][\mathbf{e}_1]_{\mathcal{B}} =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right]
,
\quad
[\mathbf{u}_1 \text{ } \mathbf{u}_2 \text{ } \mathbf{u}_3][\mathbf{e}_2]_{\mathcal{B}} =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right]
,
\quad
[\mathbf{u}_1 \text{ } \mathbf{u}_2 \text{ } \mathbf{u}_3][\mathbf{e}_3]_{\mathcal{B}} =
\left[\begin{array}{r}
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now I want a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ to satisfy
$$
T(\mathbf{u}_1) = \mathbf{e}_2
\quad
,
\quad
T(\mathbf{u}_2)=\mathbf{e}_1
\quad
,
\quad
T(\mathbf{u}_3)=\mathbf{e}_3
$$
I have accomplished this by letting $T$ be given by
$T(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{S}\mathbf{A}_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{E}}\mathbf{x}$ where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbf{S}$ is the elementary matrix for exchanging row 1 and 2
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0&1&0\\
1&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{array}\right]
$$
$T$ now satisfies the three equations.

***Here is what I am trying to understand***:
Why do you have to exchange row 1 and 2 in the transition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ to make $T(\mathbf{u}_1) = \mathbf{e}_2$ and $T(\mathbf{u}_2) = \mathbf{e}_1$. It would make more sense to me if you had to exchange column 1 and 2 since column $i$ defines $[\mathbf{e}_i]_{\mathcal{B}}$. I have really tried for a *very* long time to understand why it works to exchange the rows in the transition matrix - and what makes it work.

Please, can anyone explain the logic behind this?

Comment: Please do not delete and repost [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3245295/90543) that didn't get answered right away.

Comment: Oh, I will remember that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve chosen to decompose $T$ into $R\circ S$, where $S(\mathbf u_i)=\mathbf e_i$. The transformation $R$ then swaps $\mathbf e_1$ and $\mathbf e_2$, so $R(a\mathbf e_1+b\mathbf e_2+c\mathbf e_3)=b\mathbf e_1+a\mathbf e_2+c\mathbf e_3$, i.e., relative to this basis, $R$ swaps the first two coordinates—the first two *rows*—of the column vector $(a,b,c)^T$. Thus, it is represented by the corresponding elementary matrix.

You can also take a column-oriented view. Recall that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors. We want $R(\mathbf e_1)=\mathbf e_2$, $R(\mathbf e_2)=\mathbf e_1$ and $R(\mathbf e_3)=\mathbf e_3$, so the appropriate matrix is $\small{\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf e_2&\mathbf e_1&\mathbf e_3\end{bmatrix}}$. This matrix represents the elementary *column* operation of swapping the first two columns, but it’s symmetric, so also represents the corresponding row operation. This is true of *any* elementary matrix that represents a row swap: the matrix is symmetric, so also represents a corresponding column swap.

Comment: Thanks so much for the input! But hmm "It’s because of the symmetry of this matrix" - are you talking about $\mathbf{S}$ or $\mathbf{A}_{\mathcal{B} \leftarrow \mathcal{E}}$? It is still not 100% clear to me though - no matter which matrix you are talking about :(

Comment: @FacPam I’m talking about $\mathbf S$.

Comment: But my question is: Why do you have to exchange row 1 and 2 in the transition matrix $\mathbf{A}$ to make $T(\mathbf{u}_1) = \mathbf{e}_2$ and $T(\mathbf{u}_2) = \mathbf{e}_1$ I am still not convinced why it works to exchange the rows in the transition matrix - and what makes it work.